# Send e-mail after update statement in ASPX

Tags: asp.net, email, formview

I'm building for my project work at school a website.
The main idea is that users can report damage or report a non functioning computer.
Then the IT department can give in if they've taken any steps try fixing it and there is also a checkbox if the problem is dealth with. If the checkbox in the formview is checked and updated, there should be sent an automatic e-mail to the original user with a message that the problem is solved. I've done everything and everything works, except for the e-mail part.
Can anybody give me some advice in how I should do this? There is an unique datasource who handeles the update statement.

Yours sincerely;
A.

Here is my code:

```
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="accAfgehandeld" runat="server" 
    DataFile="~/App_data/dbMeldingen.mdb" 
    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [tblMeldingen] WHERE [MeldingID] = ?" 
    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [tblMeldingen] ([MeldingID], [Afgehandeld], [Categorie]) VALUES (?, ?, ?)" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [MeldingID], [Afgehandeld], [Categorie] FROM [tblMeldingen] WHERE ([MeldingID] = ?)" 
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE [tblMeldingen] SET [Afgehandeld] = true, [Categorie] = ? WHERE [MeldingID] = ?"
    OnUpdated="OnDSUpdatedHandler">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="MeldingID" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="MeldingID" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Afgehandeld" Type="Boolean" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Categorie" Type="Int32" />
    </InsertParameters>
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="MeldingID" QueryStringField="id" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>

        <asp:Parameter Name="Categorie" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="MeldingID" Type="Int32" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:AccessDataSource>
```

and my script in the same page:

```
<%@ Control Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="meldingendetails.ascx.vb" Inherits="meldingendetails" %>

<script runat="server">
private void OnDSUpdatedHandler(Object sender, e.Updated) {

   if (e.AffectedRows > 0) 
    {
       MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
       SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.your-isp.com");
       smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);  
   } 
}
</script>
```

Visual studio gives an error over and over again with my script, even from the void part...

Comment: Please share the research that you've done so far, as well as the code you've tried. If you haven't done any research or written any code, then go and do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set OnUpdated-handler

```
<asp:SqlDataSource
     ...
      UpdateCommand="..."
      OnUpdated="OnDSUpdatedHandler">
  </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

and use it to send email

```
<script runat="server">
private void OnDSUpdatedHandler(Object source, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e) {

   if (e.AffectedRows > 0) {
       MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
       ...
       SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.your-isp.com");
       smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);  
   } 

}
</script>
```

Comment: Hello, I've tried to do what you said I had to do, but I can't figure out how to do my script. Can you pls help me out with it? I've put the code in my question. It is an ascx page where I'm working on.

Yours sincerely

Comment: There are 9 in total..

Warning 1 Variable declaration without an 'As' clause; type of Object assumed.
Error 2 End of statement expected. 
Error 3 Statement cannot appear outside of a method body/multiline lambda. 
Error 4 Syntax error.
Error 5 Declaration expected.  
Error 6 Declaration expected. 
Error 7 Declaration expected.  
Error 8 Syntax error. 
Error 9 Syntax error.

Comment: I would take a screenshot and give it too you, but I don't have enough reputation points...

Comment: My example is in c#. If you want to use it in a vb project you should write code on vb.net. See MSDN for more examples on vb http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasourceview.onupdated(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2